# Creating the GetHashCode method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode, gethashcode

What is the best way to create your own GetHashCode method for a class in C#?  Suppose I have a simple class (which overrides the Equals method), as follows:

```
class Test
{
   public string[] names;

   public double[] values;

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
      return (obj is Test) && this.Equals((Test)obj);
   }

   public bool Equals(Test t)
   {
      return names.Equals(t.names) && values.Equals(t.values);
   }
}
```

Should I use the default code for the GetHashCode method?

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Should I base the method on the contents of my class?

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   return names.GetHashCode() + values.GetHashCode() ;
}
```

Or should I do something else?

Comment: You aren't overriding equals properly here.

Comment: Actually, I think it will lead to stackoverflow.

Comment: No, it won't overflow the stack.  However, it won't work, either.

Comment: It already has led him to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`System.Array` does not override `GetHashCode` or `Equals`, so they use reference equality.  Therefore, you shouldn't call them.

To implement `GetHashCode`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode).

To implement `Equals`, use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx) extension method.

**EDIT**: On .Net 2.0, you'll have to write your own version of `SequenceEqual`, like this:

```
public static bool SequenceEquals<T>(IList<T> first, IList<T> second) {
    if (first == second) return true;
    if (first == null || second == null) return false;

    if (first.Count != second.Count) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
        if (!first[i].Equals(second[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

You could write it to take `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IList<T>`, but it'd be somewhat slower because it wouldn't be able to exit early if the parameters have different sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and speedy response.  Is there an alternative to SequenceEqual that works with .NET framework 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

It is really important to make sure you keep the override of .GetHashCode() *in step* with .Equals().

Basically, you must make sure they consider the same fields so as not to violate the first of the three rules of GetHashCode (from [MSDN object.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx))

> If two objects compare as equal, the
>   GetHashCode method for each object
>   must return the same value. However,
>   if two objects do not compare as
>   equal, the GetHashCode methods for the
>   two object do not have to return
>   different values.

In other words, you must make sure that every time .Equals considers two instances equal, they will also have the same .GetHashCode().

As mentioned by someone else here, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) details a good implementation.
In case you are interested, I wrote up a few blog articles on investigating hash codes early last year. You can find my ramblings [here](http://blog.roblevine.co.uk/?p=15) (the first blog entry I wrote on the subject)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good discussion of the issues [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/04/25/using-equals-gethashcode-effectively.aspx), and the most recent update refers to the [BaseObject abstract class](http://sharp-architecture.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Core/DomainModel/BaseObject.cs) provided by SharpArchitecture.

If you want something more *ad hoc*, I've found that the code that ReSharper generates for Equals() and GetHashCode() is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use dotnetcore 2.1+, you can use [HashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=netcore-2.1) struct's `Combile` method to all properties, it's very easily to use and efficiency.